# bombono dvd renders menus indefinitely

Tags: linux, dvd

I'm trying to use bombono dvd authoring tool to create some DVDs. Unfortunately when I try to generate an image bombono gets to a point where it says 'rendering menu #3' and hangs there indefinitely. The whole app is responsive - so I can cancel the process, etc. What I would like is for it to finish, and write my ISO image to disk :)

Is this some known issue with bombono? Should I change something in my DVD project?

Comment: Dunno, I always use K3B - try it with a ISO of an operating system, as if it works it is a useful backup anyway

Comment: Bombono is for something different. K3B is just image/data burning util while Bombono lets you create whole DVD menus etc.

Comment: Oh... I use DeVeDe for that...

Answer (score 0):

I've been using version 1.2.1, which was distributed with my distro. I've switched to 1.2.2, downloaded from project's webpage and the whole process works now.